# Is AJAX Call to API Considered Cross Domain?

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, etsy

I'm making an ajax call to a another page on my own domain. On this page however, I make an API call to Etsy's API. I get the JSON back, format it into XML, then `echo $xml` to return the data to the original ajax call. However, `ajax.responseXML` is always null! `ajax.responseText` does contain all the info I need though.

If instead of returning the XML-formatted JSON, I just return some XML without that data, (say... `echo "<orders></orders>"`) then it works. And responseXML is not null.

So I'm thinking that even though my ajax call is calling another page on my domain, because that page is making an cross-domain call (Etsy API), it is violating the single origin policy and that is why responseXML is null?

Here's the call:

```
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
     ajax.open("GET", "OrderFetcher.php?function=sort");
     ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
     if (ajax.readyState === 4) {

     if (ajax.responseXML === null) {
          console.log("ajax.responseXML is null.");
     }

     ordersToSort = convertXmlToArray(ajax.responseXML);

};
ajax.send();
```

OrderFetcher.php contains the API call.

**EDIT**

Here's the php code ajax calls:

```
if (array_key_exists("function", $_GET)) {
if ($_GET["function"] === "sort") {

    header('Content-Type: text/xml');

    $fetchUrl = "https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/shops/__SELF__/receipts/open?limit=150&includes=Transactions,Listings";
    $orders = fetch(); // fetch() makes the API call via an Oauth object and oauth->fetch(...etc...etc...)

    $xml = "<orders>";

    foreach ($orders as $order) {
        $xml .= "<order>";
        $xml .= "<title>$order[title]</title>";
        $xml .= "<order_date>$order[order_date]</order_date>";
        $xml .= "<hidden_order_date>$order[hidden_order_date]</hidden_order_date>";
        $xml .= "<ship_date>$order[ship_date]</ship_date>";
        $xml .= "<addr_name>$order[addr_name]</addr_name>";
        $xml .= "<addr_line_1>$order[addr_line_1]</addr_line_1>";
        $xml .= "<addr_line_2>$order[addr_line_2]</addr_line_2>";
        $xml .= "<addr_city>$order[addr_city]</addr_city>";
        $xml .= "<addr_state>$order[addr_state]</addr_state>";
        $xml .= "<addr_zip>$order[addr_zip]</addr_zip>";
        $xml .= "<addr_country>$order[addr_country]</addr_country>";
        $xml .= "<price>$order[price]</price>";
        $xml .= "<quantity>$order[quantity]</quantity>";
        $xml .= "<message>$order[message]</message>";
        $xml .= "</order>";
    }

    $xml .= "</orders>";

    echo $xml;
}
```

I believe I've narrowed it down to something with the API call or ajax timing out. In the code above, if I comment out the API call and xml data and instead just do the below, it "returns" fine and `ajax.responseXML` is not null.

```
if (array_key_exists("function", $_GET)) {
    if ($_GET["function"] === "sort") {

        header('Content-Type: text/xml');

        //$fetchUrl = "https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/shops/__SELF__/receipts/open?limit=150&includes=Transactions,Listings";
        //$orders = fetch();
        // Remove xml string building code.

        echo "<xmltag>Test</xmltag>";
     }
}
```

**EDIT 2**

When I open "OrderFetcher.php?function=sort" (the ajax call) in my browser it runs for a few seconds (making API call) then gives me this:

---

This page contains the following errors:

error on line 1 at column 1: Document is empty
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

---

However, I'm not convinced something that Etsy is returning is causing invalid XML, because of these two points I mentioned above:

1. If I ignore the API data (but still make the API call) and return a simple XML string (`echo "<tag></tag>"`), then responseXML will *still* be null, even though I'm not "echo-ing" any of the data from the API call.

This doesn't work (`ajax.responseXML` is null):

```
$orders = fetch();  
echo "<xmltag>Test</xmltag>";
```

2. If I return the simple XML string (`echo "<tag></tag>"`) but *also* remove the API call altogether, suddenly responseXML is valid and not null!

This *does* work (`ajax.responseXML` is *not* null):

```
//$orders = fetch();  
echo "<xmltag>Test</xmltag>";
```

Comment: This is happening in a browser? What is the console telling you? The ajax call is not cross domain because you're calling a script on the same site.. The PHP may do a call to a remote endpoint but that has nothing to do with your JS

Comment: responseXML is only filled if the data being returned can be parsed as XML/HTML. Might need to tell the XHR to expect xml or make sure your server script is outputing the correct content-type header

Comment: You might need to show your php code. it looks like you are constructing the XML in your php file. So show how you are returning the response from the php file

Comment: Ok I've narrowed it down to the API call - I think because it's taking too long. It takes about 5-7 seconds, before that ajax tries to use responsXML and that's why it's empty. There is a way to set a timeout for an ajax call correct?

Comment: @Dale the console is showing an error and stopping execution when it tries to call a 'getElementsByTagName' on ajax.responseXML, it says it's null.

Comment: the request taking too long shouldn't be causing this problem. The request failing or timing out, however, very well could.

Comment: @KevinB the API call does return successfully, ajax.responseText contains all the data I need (except with my added XML tags) and I've tested the API call when isolated. Perhaps ajax tries to access responseXML before the API call has finished?

Comment: or, perhaps the xml isn't xml? opening the endpoint (your server) directly in the browser would tell you if it was invalid and why. Given your code, i could think of quite a few values that etsy could return that would result in  your endpoint generating invalid xml.

Comment: @KevinB I though that too, but I don't think this is the case based on my second edit (see above). Even if I ignore the data returned from the API call, and echo a simple XML string, ajax.responseXML is still null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow this was just a noob mistake. In my `fetch()` function (that makes the API call) I had an `echo "something"` in there. Therefore that was getting executed before `echo $xml` causing the errors I was experiencing.